# How to convert dynamic NSString into JSON format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsjsonserialization

please help me anyone i am trying to convert NSString into JSON for taking specific data from that string. This was my string and i try to convert from NSString into JSON. That string was dynamically fetch into that jsonString that was i paste in that string below.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{status=success&amp;unmappedstatus=captured&amp;instrument_type=iOS&amp;}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

the result will be displayed as null that i displays in NSLog and even in UIalert view

```
NSLog(@"-->>JSON_data: %@",json);
```

please help me anyone for this..

Comment: 1. You always get data as NSData first. Avoid converting it to NSString but pass it to JSONObjectWithData directly. 2. That string is NOT JSON. It looks a little bit like JSON, but it isn't JSON. 3. Find out where that string comes from and what format it is supposed to be.

Comment: thats string comes as per my api success response .. i need how to align the string as like @maya answer parsing ....

Answer (score 6):

You should store your string as

```
    NSString *jsonString = @"{\"status\":\"success&amp\",\"unmappedstatus\":\"captured&amp\",\"instrument_type\":\"iOS&amp\"}";
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks @maya its work.. but that string comes as dynamic, how to i align that string like u mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

It returns `nil` if it failed to parse. Use something like the following to get the error description:

```
NSError *error;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
   NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string what you are trying to convert into NSData and than back to JSON is not a valid JSON string.

Therefore you get null JSON data.
This is what your string should look like:

```
{
"status":"success&amp",
"unmappedstatus" : "captured&amp" , 
"instrument_type" : "iOS&amp"
}
```

You can validate a string as JSON under this link:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Yes bro its showing undefined.. that means this string was wrong one right, please tell how to align its correctly if u known.. Thanks..

Comment: well it is doable for sure, you need to find some logic in the string based on what you can parse it into this form.
Maybe it would worth reconsidering, what do you need from this.

Comment: i need to align the string as whatever the @maya shown in the string thats work fine for me,